# Order products in a category with "New" items listed first in Magento

Tags: magento, categories

When displaying a Magento category is it possible to have any new products (products that have a "new from" and "new to" date) listed at the beginning of the collection so they show up on the first page of the category instead of the default location based on the current sort?

Would it be necessary to have two queries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Code to **sort products** by **news_from_date** and **news_to_date**:-

```
$todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                      0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
                      1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
                    ), 'left')
                 ->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc');
```

You can view the new products code at the class **Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New**

> (app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/New.php)

Hope this helps.